# Accepting an answer of another/duplicate question

Tags: support, answers, exact-duplicates

My question turned out to be a duplicate. Yet, it gathered some good answers. However, one of the answers to the other, first, question suits me best. Can I accept it as best answer to my question?

Comment: I think not. You can only accept answers to your own questions. But nothing stops you flagging in an edit to your question that there is a better answer elsewhere and that's a fine positive contribution.

Comment: This appears to refer to http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/91750/how-is-the-formula-for-the-standard-error-of-the-slope-in-linear-regression-deri

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Nice thought. The correct thing to do would be to vote up the answer, which you will be able to do with another 2 reputation...

Comment: Mysteriously, some more reputation has appeared. You could now upvote it and mention its value in your question.

Answer (score 5):

To answer your specific question, as the comments already stated, **no** you can not accept an answer to a different question. So in light of that, reasonable actions to take are:

1. Flag your question to be merged with the duplicate.
2. Answer *your own* question, given the information in the other.

As Nick Cox says in the comments make sure to link to the other question, both for sake of proper attribution as well as creating a strong indicator between the two questions. (The linked and related questions bars on the right hand side are wonderful for navigating similar questions.)

Given the disruption that occurs when merging questions together - especially if your question already has an answer(s) to it - I would prefer option 2 unless the questions are flagrantly duplicate.